# Vector components vs coordinates?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, covariance

While studying about covariant and contravariant vectors I came across this description on Wikipedia

"A contravariant vector has **components that "transform as the coordinates do"** under changes of coordinates (and so inversely to the transformation of the reference axes), including rotation and dilation. The vector itself does not change under these operations; instead, the components of the vector change in a way that cancels the change in the spatial axes, in the same way that co-ordinates change. In other words, if the reference axes were rotated in one direction, the component representation of the vector would rotate in exactly the opposite way. Similarly, if the reference axes were stretched in one direction, the components of the vector, like the co-ordinates, would reduce in an exactly compensating way...."

Aren't the components of the vector same as the coordinate of the vectors? A vector is defined by a set of numbers with respect to a given set of basis vectors. These "basis vectors" are what I understand to be the reference axes and the "set of numbers" to be the components of the vectors. Arnt these components the same a coordinates?

Comment: I would be really grateful for any help with this please. Thank you

Comment: This is a great explanation:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CliW7kSxxWU&t=0s&index=11&list=PLRjrMKQysHESIenu99dJugaJHVBQkUEmC. But what they mean by "coordinates" is not given in the video. Coordinate means Coordinate functions (ie coordinate vector something like [1,0,0,0]) which would map vector v to its contravariant components.